# Checking if defined and has a Value

Tags: java, javascript, web-scraping, jsoup

I have some javascript which uses jsoup to extract info from a webform. All works great if the textarea Element is found on the page. But if it cant find it throws an error "
Variable ASRRMK is undefined."

```
asrRmk  = asrRmk.select("textarea[name=asr_remarks]").first();

if (asrRmk != null && asrRmk != undefined) {
 asrRmk  = asrRmk.html() 

data = { name="asr_remarks"
        , value=asrRmk 
        , type="textarea"
};
```

so what I am trying to do is check if asrRmk is actually defined and has a value, if it is defined, I want to append it to my array, otherwise I will leave it of.

Comment: What's this got to do with ColdFusion? It's a JS question.

Comment: because I run the java script inside coldfusion

Comment: I removed those tags and added web scraping and java. Adam is right. You may use any number of technologies, but that doesn't mean they all relate for the problem at hand.

Comment: That's incorrect because something which might work in normal javascript does not work in coldfusion implementation. And the question is less about the scraping then how to check if variable exists and has a value. But I guess Adam feels he needs to give his useless input

Comment: @NoSoup4you ColdFusion would not have any affect on the code you've  posted.

Comment: @NoSoup4you Is everything you posted meant be JavaScript code or are you trying to intermix JavaScript and ColdFusion variables?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do

```
String html = "<div><textarea name=\"asr_remarks\"></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("textarea[name=asr_remarks]");

if(elements != null && !elements.isEmpty()) {
    //do something
    String asrRmk = elements.first().html();
    System.out.println(asrRmk);
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work either. if I run your script I get Variable NULL is undefined

elements = doc.select("textarea[name=asr_remarks]");
9560 : 
9561 :  if(elements != null && !elements.isEmpty()) {
9562 :     //do something
9563 :     asrRmk = elements.first().html();